# Problem by passing components with images

Tags: reactjs, image, jpeg

I just tried to create a component which includes a .jpg and pass it to the App.js (I used "create-react-app").
Unfortunately, my browser tells me about a compiling error:

**Failed to compile 

./src/bla/components/Pics.js

Module not found: Can't resolve './bla/tb1.jpg' in 'C:\lernordner\testapp\test\src\bla\components'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.**
'''

Can someone tell me what I`m doing wrong? The directory path is okay.
Thank you!

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pics from './bla/components/Pics.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Pics />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Pics.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './bla/test.jpg'; 

function Pics() {
  return <img src={Test} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Pics;
```

Comment: Could you include the error in your question? [It should work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5r4oqp09m).

Answer (score 1):

import statement in your code will import the whole image file. Now if that is correct, Having the whole file contents assigned to src attribute image shouldnt display image.  You have to pass the image path in src attribute.
Something like this:

```
function Pics() {
    return <img src={'assets/test.jpg'} alt="Logo" />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this? if it still doesn't work it's problem with directory

```
const Pics = () => {
  return <img src={Test} alt="Logo" />;
}
```